# Store paragraphs with indentations in postgres with prisma ( such as for markdown )

Tags: sql, postgresql, prisma

### Problem

Recently, I made markdown text editor, and want to store markdown format to database. So I am wondering if it is possible to store paragraphs with indentations in postgres with prisma model. I tested when `detail` property has only `string`, and indentations of the paragraph weren't saved.

How can I save strings with multiple lines with prisma?

### model

```js
model Post {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  title     String   @db.VarChar(255)
  detail    String   //This part 
}
```

### Prisma Studio

[image]

### Browser

[image]

Comment: For indentations can't you just store `\n` (new line) and `\t` (tab) in string format?

Comment: No, I thought of that but it didn't.
I wonder how stackoverflow post store text in a way recognizing each indentation

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your data is being stored correctly, it's just a matter of how you convert the Markdown to HTML.

I've found that using `@db.VarChar(10000)` has historically worked when storing rich text (HTML) or other text with special formatting, which I could then display elsewhere.

https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#string